# Does 3D printed Alumide out gas after printing?

Tags: print-material, safety, alumide

Does 3D printed Alumide outgas or is it inert? I.e. If I printed a box with it and stored paper in that box for 100 years would the paper become damaged by out gassing?

I noticed that [NASA has a list of materials that out gas](https://data.nasa.gov/Applied-Science/Outgassing-Db/r588-f7pr).

But I'm not sure exactly what polymers are in 3D printed Alumide...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alumide is, as [this question explains](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/19072/8884) made up entirely of Aluminium Grit and Polyamide 12 dust.

The Database contains one entry for Polyamide 12 (by [filtering for it here](https://data.nasa.gov/d/r588-f7pr/visualization)):

[image: Polyamide 12 - ID GSFC4067 - MFR HUL - TML 0.76 - Category 0 - CVCM 0.02 - Space Code 1 - WVR N/A - Material Usage MOLD CPND - Cure N/A]

Some other items of similar material (Nylon 6 & Nylon 12) are also in the database:

[image]

As a result of the material being essentially aluminium and PA12, I would take the PA12 values for an estimation until the material was tested properly.