# What polymers are used in 3D printed Alumide?

Tags: print-material, alumide

Does anyone know what polymers are used in 3D printed Alumide? I know it has Al and nylon, but does it have anything else?

NASA has a database of materials that out gas and I'd like to see if Alumide out gasses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alumide is a registered trademark. It's source words are *Alu*munium and Polya*mide*. The first materials known under this name were sold in 2007.

According to my materials provider, the ratio is but for tiny tollerances exactly 50% Polyamide-12 dust that is enriched with 50% aluminium particles and the material is used without special alterations to the machine in a typical nylon Selective Laser Sintering machine using a modified profile for PA12. Its [MSDS](https://www.shapeways.com/rrstatic/material_docs/msds-alumide.pdf) only lists those two components, so there is nothing but those in it usually.

As a result, the polymer binder is only [Polyamide 12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nylon_12)